# elegant code to extract a subset array from an object array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following object array:

```
var myObject =
[
{X:1, Y:2, Z:3},
{X:4, Y:5, Z:6},
{X:7, Y:8, Z:9},
]
```

What is some elegant code to get the following output?:

```
var subset = [ Y:2, Y:5, Y:8 ]
```

Comment: `var subset = [ Y:2, Y:5, Y:8 ]` is invalid syntax. Do you mean: `var subset = { Y1:2, Y2:5, Y3:8 }` or do you mean: `var subset = [ { Y:2 }, { Y:5 }, { Y:8 } ]`? SInce the first one will use `array.reduce()` and the second will use `array.map()`

Comment: @Shilly note that your first subset is *also* wrong, as your declaring the same key multiple times. It's almost certainly the second.

Comment: @Jared Smith Yeah, I already editted it and added a number to the keys. Noticed myself 10sec after posting.

Answer (score 6):

```
const arr = [
  {X:1, Y:2, Z:3},
  {X:4, Y:5, Z:6},
  {X:7, Y:8, Z:9},
];
const output = arr.map(({Y}) => ({Y})); // [{Y: 2}, {Y: 5}, {Y: 8}]
```

This uses an arrow function mapped over the array, destructures the `Y` property out of each item, and uses object property shorthand to return a new object with just the Y property for each item of the array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just had to write a similar answer to a related but different question yesterday, so I had it fresh in my head :)

Comment: That may be personal taste, but I find this syntax highly disturbing and hard to read (maybe lack of experience with decomposition?). This is a very good answer though and maybe the _most JS_ answer here.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat thank you, I went for maximum brevity (OP requested eloquence). A perhaps more readable version would be T.J. Crowder's although both need the extra parens so the braces don't get mistaken for a function body instead of an object by the parser.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat: ("Destructuring") Yeah, it can really throw you at first glance -- and second glance, and third. :-) Once you get used to it it's powerful, but like any power, it can be abused. The symmetry is fun, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it would be *really* cryptic if they let you automagically return the destructured item. But would a hypothetical `arr.map(({Y}));` return the value of `Y` or `{Y:Y}`? Enquiring minds want to know...

Comment: @JaredSmith: I think it'd have to be `Y`. (But as you probably know, `arr.map(({Y}))` is already valid syntax: it calls `arr.map` passing in a new object with a `Y` property initialized from an in-scope `Y`. `map` would then, of course, complain that it wasn't a function, assuming `arr` had any entries.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder assuming that there was in fact a `Y` in scope and not a `ReferenceError` first. But I think since the existing syntax would throw a `TypeError` at best it could theoretically be added. Not that you'd ever actually want to *do* that.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Well, the problem is that `map` is just a function, so its expectations of the parameter it receives are irrelevant to the parsing and interpretation of the expression defining the argument we pass it. `arr.map(({Y}))` wouldn't fly with TC39 as `someOtherFunction(({Y}))` is valid and potentially in use. Perhaps `arr.map(=>({Y}))` but...good luck. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`map` with an arrow function is fairly elegant:

```js
var myObject =
[
{X:1, Y:2, Z:3},
{X:4, Y:5, Z:6},
{X:7, Y:8, Z:9},
];
var result = myObject.map(e => ({Y: e.Y}));
console.log(result);
```

Even more so if you [add in some destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907361/157247) as Jared did. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the map function

```js
var myObject = [ 
  {X:1, Y:2, Z:3},
  {X:4, Y:5, Z:6},
  {X:7, Y:8, Z:9},
];

var test = myObject.map(row => { 
  return {
      Y: row.Y 
  };
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand the desired output notation put you can use a map anyways:

```
myObject.map(element => element.Y) // Output [2, 5, 8]
myObject.map(element => ({Y: element.Y})) // Output [{Y: 2}, {Y: 5}, {Y: 8}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how reusable you want your code to be, I find it fairly elegant to add some currying :

```js
const arr = [
    {X:1, Y:2, Z:3},
    {X:4, Y:5, Z:6},
    {X:7, Y:8, Z:9},
];

const get = prop => o => ({[prop]: o[prop]});
const extract = arr => prop => arr.map(get(prop));

const result = extract(arr)('Y');
console.log(result);
```